# Import XML into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying to insert a XML into a SQL Server table, but I get an error:

> Msg 2205, Level 16, State 1, Line 10
>   XQuery [value()]: ")" was expected.

Code:

```
 DECLARE @XML XML = '<list>
    <object Index="0"   Type="0"    Name="obj1" Level="6" />
    <object Index="1"   Type="0"    Name="obj2" Level="9"    />
</list>'
INSERT INTO dbo.testt(test1, test2, test3, test4)
SELECT
    test1 = Events.value('@Index','int'),
    test2 = Events.value('@Type','varchar'),
    test3 =Events.value('@Name','varchar'),
    test4 =Events.value('(@Level','int')
FROM
 @XML.nodes('/list/object') AS testtt(Events)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a `(` before `@Level`

```
test4 =Events.value('(@Level','int')
```

should be:

```
test4 =Events.value('@Level','int')
```